# Creating a query in MS Access that returns all entries if no input is supplied or the selected entries if input is supplied

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm trying to create a query that will accept input from a form (from a set of 3 radio buttons, one for "male" one for "female" and one for "either") and return all the entries of the specified input.

I'm a bit of a newbie to MS Access so apologies if this is a super basic question. I've looked a lot online to find a solution but can't find one that works!

The query I have so far is this:

```
   IIf([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup]. 
   [Value]=1,"M",IIf([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup]. 
   [Value]=2,"F",IIf([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup]. 
   [Value]=3,([Child Details].[Gender])="M" Or ([Child Details]. 
   [Gender])="F")))
```

If it helps the SQL code for the query is this:

```
   WHERE ((([Child Details].Gender)=IIf([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]! 
    [GenderOptionGroup].[Value]=1,"M",IIf([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]! 
    [GenderOptionGroup].[Value]=2,"F",IIf([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]! 
    [GenderOptionGroup].[Value]=3,([Child Details].[Gender])="M" Or ([Child 
    Details].[Gender])="F"))))
```

I can make this work for when Male and Female are selected, but unfortunately I can't get it to work if I select either. In this case it should be just returning all entries regardless of what gender is in the field but it just returns nothing. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that if the final option is selected, the resulting `WHERE` clause would read:

```sql
where [Child Details].Gender = ([Child Details].[Gender]="M" or [Child Details].[Gender]="F")
```

And since `[Child Details].Gender` is string-valued, it will never equal the boolean value returned by the bracketed expression.

---

There are multiple ways to achieve this: one possible method is using a combination of the [`like`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931) operator and the [`choose`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-function-76230415-910f-463a-a799-cf7e90aa7fd4) function:

```sql
where 
    [child details].gender like 
    choose([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup],"M","F","[MF]")
```

Alternatively, you could use use the [`switch`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) function in a similar way:

```sql
where 
    [child details].gender like 
    switch
    (
        [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup]=1,"M",
        [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup]=2,"F",
        [Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup]=3,"[MF]"
    )
```

Or, just using boolean logic:

```sql
where 
([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup] in (1,3) and [child details].gender = "M") or
([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup] in (2,3) and [child details].gender = "F")
```

Or, if you don't wish to restrict the results returned when the third option is selected, precede all of the above filters with:

```sql
([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup] = 3) or
```

For example:

```sql
where 
    ([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup] = 3) or
    ([child details].gender = choose([Forms]![AgeRangeQueryForm]![GenderOptionGroup],"M","F"))
```

Comment: Unless there is a third gender (unknown?) then the either option could be simplified to return `true` and only apply a filter if a single gender is selected.

Comment: @manotheshark I have updated my answer to reflect your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks @LeeMac for your detailed response.